# When opening app via email attachment multiple instances seem to open. How do you do this right?

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, android-activity, titanium

What is supposed to happen:
1.) receive email with a custom file with extension ".custom"
2.) click on file and select "open with CustomApp"
3.) App reads file and stores the data somewhere
4.) Ideally the user could just continue to use the app normally

I have managed to setup custom filters:

```
<activity android:name=".CustomappActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="content" android:pathPattern=".*\\.custom" android:mimeType="*/*"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What happens now when I open a .custom file in CustomApp?
It seems to me as if regardless of whether the app is currently running in the background or not a new CustomappActivity gets launched. However both activities seem to share a namespace or something, because the newly launched one is not able to get the WebView UI up and running. So this seemed to be leading me nowhere.

What I have now done is implement a "check for intent" before I start my app properly. If it was started with an intent I just store the data of the .custom file in my App.Properties and then try to close the currently running instance of the app (via `Ti.Android.currentActivity.finish()`).
However the Activity (or something else) seems to still be running, because when I open the app back up (even if it was running while I did the other things, once I select it in the task manager it starts up from the beginning) only bad things happen:
Every call from the WebView to the app and vice versa gets made more than once (depending on how often the App has been started after the first opening of the .custom file). This obviously makes the app unusable because nothing works.

Even killing the app in the task manager does not always reset everything so that a call only gets made once.

Can anyone guess what's up here?

Or even better give me guidelines on how to implement the use case properly?
While I do not fully understand the whole activity complex and how it interacts with appcelerator I'd reckon that this may not happen if I wouldn't call my main launcher activity with the intent but another custom activity that's only responsible for importing the data from the .custom file and nothing else. But how does one create a custom activity with titanium?

Thanks for any help or nudge in the right direction!

Comment: I think what you see is related to https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-15253. Would there be a way you can pass a singleTask flag with the intent?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no real control over the intent since it gets created by Gmail or another email app.

You seem to have managed to create a custom activity ('incoming.js') though? 
If I could have an activity separate from the main one that handles the data import and then finishes (and of course not interferes with the main activity after) that would also be fine.

Where did you put the <android><activities><activity> (...) code block? Because whether I put it in tiapp.xml or the android manifest it gets ignored during compiling.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen sorry, I forgot to tag you.

Comment: See http://fokkezb.nl/2013/08/26/url-schemes-for-ios-and-android-1/ - but I didn't create another activity, although indeed you could. Just add another <activity> element on the same level and see http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-activities